# $\int_{B} \mathbf{1}_{A}d\mathbb P = \int_{B} \mathbb P(A | \mathcal B) d\mathbb P$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space, $\mathcal B$ a sub-$\sigma$-algeba of $\mathcal A$, $B \in \mathcal B$ with $\mathbb P(B) > 0$ and $A \in \mathcal A$ with $\mathbb P(A | \mathcal B) > \varepsilon$ almost surely. The task is to show that $\mathbb P(A|B)  > \varepsilon$.

I saw the following solution: $\mathbb P(A \cap B) = \int_{B} \mathbf{1}_{A}d\mathbb P = \int_{B} \mathbb P(A | \mathcal B) d\mathbb P > \varepsilon \mathbb P(B)$.

The first and the last equality is clear to me. But I don't see why $\mathbf{1}_{A} = \mathbb P(A | \mathcal B)$ holds there because $\mathbb P(A | \mathcal B) := \mathbb E[\mathbf{1}_{A} | \mathcal B]$ and to my knowledge $A \cap B$ is in general not in $\mathcal B$.

Comment: It's the very definition of the conditional expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $\mathbf{1}_{A} = \mathbb P(A | \mathcal B)$ does not hold.

But $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ and $\mathbb P(A | \mathcal B)$ do have the same integral over $B$, by definition of the conditional expectation.

Use the definition $\mathbb P(A | \mathcal B) = \mathbb E[\mathbf1_A | \mathcal B]$.

Comment: Now I am back on the right track I think. Can you just tell me if my argumentation is now correct?: Define $Y :=  \mathbb E[ \mathbf{1}_{A} | \mathcal B]$. Then by the definition of the conditional expectation: $\mathbb E[\mathbf{1}_{A} \mathbf{1}_{B}] = \mathbb E[Y \mathbf{1}_{B}]$. But $\mathbb E[Y \mathbf{1}_{B}] = \int_{B} Y d\mathbb P$ and $E[\mathbf{1}_{A} \mathbf{1}_{B}] = \mathbb P(A \cap B)$. The rest follows immediately.